# Example of a relatively large open source codebase/application that is written in Procedural style as opposed to OOP style

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, procedural

I've been a professional game programmer for more than 10 years, and a programmer for more than 14. For this entire time, I've been coding in OOP style and, as a senior programmer, I have extensive knowledge in OOP best practices.
I just finished watching a video arguing against OOP and the issues revolved around it (overengineered classes, a lot of state to be managed, the complexity of class relationships and encapsulation etc) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM1iUe6IofM). I certainly understand where the author is coming from, and there are best practices to address those issues, which I won't go into right now. However the author argues procedural programming, with many free, pure functions, with very few classes and a reduced amount of state is the superior way of programming. On paper, they present a compelling argument.

However, I would like to see an example of procedural programming applied successfully to a relatively large codebase with multiple contributors. I tried to find an example and I could not. The proof is in the pudding, as they say. Can anyone provide some example(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Linux kernel code base is procedural and has more than 8 million lines of code.

The new projects like Amazon FireCracker ( firecracker-microvm.github.io) is written in Rust programming language which is not purely object oriented.